# How to find the $C$ constant in a polytropic evolution of a piston/cylinder system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have this thermodynamic problem in one of my chemical engineering class:

> ''The R-410A refrigerant is contained in a single piston / cylinder arrangement. temperature of 20 C and a titer x = 1. An expansion which can be described by the following mathematical relation: P = C/v (v is specific volume) where C is a constant to be defined. Determine the final temperature and specific volume if the final pressure is 100kPa.''

I've found that the R-410A can be considered as a perfect gas, but I don't know if this polytropic evolution is also isothermal, so I'm not sure how to find the answer.

Comment: What does a titer x = 1 mean?  Do you have thermodynamic tables for 410A or a p-H diagram?

Comment: @ChetMiller It is the proportion by mass of vapor in the liquid-vapor mixture. So x=1 means it is all vapor. I have thermodynamic tables for 410A. Thank you!

Comment: So, from your tables, what is the equilibrium vapor pressure and specific volume of saturated vapor at 20 C?